# What makes Hubstaff Client low on Memory Usage?

Tags: desktop-application, tauri

[Hubstaff low memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huZlG.png)
I'm trying to build a desktop app like hubstaff where it only consumes a small quantity of memory usage.. Does anyone knows a technology that has a low memory usage like Hubstaff? Thanks

I tried Tauri but it consumes around 50mb, I am expecting a low memory usage with it based on the details I found on the internet, but it's not what I wanted.

Comment: Looking at its License and the installed files it seems to be mostly fltk and cairo.
Either way, a memory usage of <10MB total is virtually impossible with webtech based guis, so projects like Tauri, Electron or even CEF won't be able to match that.